# Excel VBA Autofilters inside functions

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub TurnAutoFilterOn()
'check for filter, turn on if none exists
  If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
  End If
End Sub
```

Works well and turns on the AutoFilter.

```
Function Req(ByVal MCode As String) As Integer
    TurnAutoFilterOn
End Function
```

Doesn't work.

```
Function Req(ByVal MCode As String) As Integer
'check for filter, turn on if none exists
  If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
  End If
End Function
```

Doesn't work.

Is excel vba autofilters supposed to be working only under SUBs and not in Functions?

Comment: If you are calling the function from VBA then it will work but if you are using it as a UDF then it will not work as a UDF will not allow you to change the autofilter like it doesn't allow you to change values of other cells

Comment: The above function is not a UDF..

Comment: I understood what you mean by UDF... Yes I was trying to call the function from an excel cell... From the function I'm trying to call the SUB defined for autofilter, still excel is not enabling autofilter.

Comment: If you are calling from an excel cell then it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The above commenters are right regarding updating the workbook (i.e. any cells) from a function invoked by a cell - it is not allowed/supported.

Excel provides a workbook reclaculation model in which it can precompute inter-cell dependencies based on the cell formulas.  This allows for a (relatively) efficient propagation of changes from their original sources to the cells that depend upon them.  It propagates changes repeatedly (i.e. recursively) until they've been propagated to cells that are not referenced in other formulas, when the workbook relaculation is completed.  It does NOT allow cell formulas to modify any cells in the workbook; if it were to support that it would effectively invalidate (or at least dramatically weaken) the pre-computed formula-based dependency analysis, and require another calculation model (that would likely much less efficient).  (Circular cell references (direct or indirectly) are also problematic for this method, which makes history functions a bit tricky.)

However, what you can do is record some data in a VBA data structure to save for later use (in the example below, the very simple public gx, but such data structure can by almost of any complexity).  You can then use that recorded data after a workbook recalculation using events.  The Worksheet Change Event is way to run some code after the calculation (you write subroutine Worksheet_Calculate and put it in the worksheet), at a time when it will be OK to modify the cells.  There is also a Workbook_SheetCalculation which goes in the code for ThisWorkbook, which might be of interest.

In "ThisWorkbook":

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    MsgBox "gx=" & gx
    Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = gx
End Sub
```

In "Module1":

```
Public gx As Long

Function MyFormula(x As Long) As String
   gx = x
   MyFormula = "hello"
End Function
```

In Sheet1, cell A5:

=MyFormula(A4)

You'll get a pop up in a context where gx was set to the number in A4 (showing the storing of data from the run of the formula), and, modifying a worksheet as well.  Now, modify A4 with another number and you'll see the results because changing A4 triggers a recalculation.

(Note that you may also be interested in the Workbook_SheetChange event as an alternative to the SheetCalculate event.)

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, when you change the workbook within an Event triggered by change or calculation, the event will get likely be triggered yet again.  So, you can prepare for that with code that works fine if run twice or put in some code to clear the state on the first invocation, so a subsequent invocation can test for that and do nothing.